# Ubuntu denied access to remove directory

Tags: command-line

I tried this command:
`rmdir -r android-studio`

I am getting this error:
`rmdir: failed to remove 'android-studio': Permission denied`

How can I fix this?
[I am using Ubuntu in dual boot with windows 10]

Comment: You may need to elevate privileges with the aid of `sudo`

Comment: Please edit your question and include more context and details. You should include the command that you are attempting along with the full output

Answer (score 0):

guiverc told the right:

`sudo rm -r android-studio`

It works.

Answer (score 0):

If it doesn't remove the directory with sudo try installing midnight commander

```
sudo apt install mc
```

then

```
sudo mc
```

find the path and then press F8